# Ruby under Rubymine debugger variables constantly display "collecting data"

Tags: ruby, debugging, rubymine

I am using Rubymine 5.4.3.2.1 with Ruby 1.9.3 under Windows 8. Debugging even the simplest programs is impossible because at the breakpoint variable display, drilling down on any complex variable ends up in an unending "collecting data" response. Debugging is useless.

I've been working with JetBrains for 2 days to solve this.  They cannot recreate it.  However, I have seen a number of posts where other users have had this problem and migrated to other debuggers.  I'd rather stay on Rubymine if I can fix this.  But, I need to use the debugger.

JetBrains has had me dump them varied information, disable the firewall, give them sample code, show them screencasts, reinstall gems and provide them a thread dump which they will look at next week.  They asked me to try it on another workstation, which I don't have, and upgrade to Ruby 2.0, which wouldn't help since the code I'm using isn't compatible.  I have searched (and searched and searched) for an answer.  I have reinstalled Rubymine. All, to no avail.

Is anyone else seeing this problem?  Has anyone else resolved this problem?  Do you have any recommendations for me?

If someone else is seeing it, please report it to JetBrains.

Comment: JetBrains had me try it on 1.9.3p448 and it worked fine.  My problem is that I am using Bitnami RubyStack and kind of have my hands tied there.  I have yet to decide how to work this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading to current Ruby, such as 1.9.3p448, fixes this.

It turns out that BitNami has made a recent change in Rubystack that downgraded Ruby while applying the TCS (The Code Source) performance patches as of their Rubystack version 1.9.3-8. They provide inadequate notice or explanation of what they did or why. They did this only for Windows which makes no sense because that is a development environment. As of this date, Rubystack 1.9..3-12 is being distributed with this change that downgrades Ruby to 1.9.3p231.

BitNami Rubystack users that upgrade may see a rash of problems.  If they choose to do so, they need to make sure they reference the TCS Ruby source code for builds.  BitNami does have a recommendation regarding how to upgrade to current Rubyinstaller versions, which is a relief. You can see this at:

[What Ruby source matches Rubystack 1.9.3-12?](http://answers.bitnami.com/questions/14673/what-ruby-source-matches-rubystack-193-12?page=1#14677)

My fix is going to be to download the RubyInstaller 7zip files and change the content of the BitNami Ruby folder for this other one as referenced here:

[Is the Rubystack version outdated in release 1.9.3-12?](http://answers.bitnami.com/questions/14372/is-the-rubystack-version-outdated-in-release-193-12)

Comment: I did a gem list to get a record of my installed gems, uninstalled Rubystack, installed Rubystack, used Rubyinstaller to bring it to native p448 and then used my gem list to ensure I had all my gems.  Tests run great.  All is well.

Comment: Current update: I have found an issue compiling native extensions.  It says that I must install the development kit first.  The development kit comes as part of the Rubystack.  Searches so far indicate there is a mix of 32bit and 64bit support which causes this somewhat erroneous error message.  I haven't yet fixed this.

Comment: I don't have an answer for this problem at the moment.  I'll update this question if and when I do get an answer.  In the mean time, I still happen to have the Rubystack 1.9.3-6 package so I am going back to it since the problem arose at 1.9.3-8.  I am hopeful I'll be fine there for now until BitNami figures out their issues.